# Push Notification service is not working, When device is switch off

Tags: objective-c, web-services, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have implement Apple Push Notification in my application.

It's working fine when my iPhone is on.

Now, when I switch off my iPhone and fire notification from the server, it's successfully sent.

but, When I switch on my iPhone, I am not getting any notification.

So, what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

> Apple Push Notification service includes a default Quality of Service
>   (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function.
>
> If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline,
>   the notification is stored for a limited period of time, and delivered
>   to the device when it becomes available.
>
> Only one recent notification for a particular application is stored.
>   If multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each
>   new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. This
>   behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as
>   coalescing notifications.
>
> If the device remains offline for a long time, any notifications that
>   were being stored for it are discarded.